# Perl with FASTA sequence extraction has problems (only) with first sequence

Tags: perl, fasta

I am using a function/subroutine `extract_seq` available on internet to extract sequences in FASTA files. Briefly:

- A sequence begins with first line identified by '>', followed by ID and other information separated by spaces
- Subsequent lines (not beginning with '>' have multiple strings
- A FASTA file can have 1 or more sequences
- Bug is that the output has additional '>' character for first sequence (only) causing consistency problems.

Program works fine in extracting sequences based on ID except for additional '>' in case of first sequence. Could you please suggest a solution as well as reason for the bug? A simple regex would fix the problem but I do not feel good about fixing bugs that I cannot understand.

The Perl script is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;

    my $seq_all = "seq_all.fa";    # all proteins in fasta format

    foreach my $q_seq ("A0A1D8PC43","A0A1D8PC38") {
        print "Querying $q_seq\n";
        &extract_seq($seq_all, $q_seq);
    }

exit 0;

sub extract_seq
{
    open(my $fh, ">query.seq");

    my $seq_all = $_[0];
    my $lookup = $_[1];

    local $/ = "\n>";

    @ARGV = ($seq_all);
    while (my $seq = <>) {
        chomp $seq;
        my ($id) = $seq =~ /^>*(\S+)/;
        if ($id eq $lookup) {
            print "$seq\n";
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

The FASTA file is:

```
>A0A1D8PC43 A0A1D8PC43_CANAL Diphosphomevalonate decarboxylase
MYSASVTAPVNIATLKYWGKRDKSLNLPTNSSISVTLSQDDLRTLTTASASESFEKDQLW
LNGKLESLDTPRTQACLADLRKLRASIEQSPDTPKLSQMKLHIVSENNFPTAAGLASSAA
GFAALVSAIAKLYELPQDMSELSKIARKGSGSACRSLFGGFVAWEMGTLPDGQDSKAVEI
APLEHWPSLRAVILVVSDDKKDTPSTTGMQSTVATSDLFAHRIAEVVPQRFEAMKKAILD
KDFPKFAELTMKDSNSFHAVCLDSYPPIFYLNDTSKKIIKMVETINQQEVVAAYTFDAGP
NAVIYYDEANQDKVLSLLYKHFGHVPGWKTHYTAETPVAGVSRIIQTSIGPGPQETSESL
TK
>A0A1D8PC56 A0A1D8PC56_CANAL Uncharacterized protein OS=Candida
MSDTKKTTETDSEVGYLDIYLRFNDDMEKDYCFQVKTTTVFKDLYKVFRTLPISLRPSVF
YHAQPIGFKKSVSPGYLTQDGNFIFDEDSQKQAVPVNDNDLINETVWPGQLILPVWQFND
FGFYSFLAFLACWLYTDLPDFISPTPGICLTNQMTKLMAWVLVQFGKDRFAETLLADLYD
TVGVGAQCVFFGFHIIKCLFIFGFLYTGVFNPMRVFRLTPRSVKLDVTKEELVKLGWTGT
RKATIDEYKEYYREFKINQHGGMIQAHRAGLFNTLRNLGVQLESGEGYNTPLTEENKLRT
MRQIVEDAKKPDFKLKLSYEYFAELGYVFATNAENKEGSELAQLIKQYRRYGLLVSDQRI
KTVVRARKGETDEEKPKVEEVVEE
>A0A1D8PC67 A0A1D8PC67_CANAL Bfa1p OS=Candida albicans (strain
MVSDKLTLLRQFSEEDELFGDIEGIDYHDGETLKINKFSFPSSASSPSFAITGQSPNMRS
INGKRITRETLSEYSEENETDLTSEFSDQEFEWDGFNKNQSIYQQMNQRLIATKVAKQRE
AEREQRELMQKRHKDYDPNQTLRLKDFNKLTNENLTLLDQLDDEKTVNYEYVRDDVEDFA
QGFDKDFETKLRIQPSMPTLRSNAPTLKKYKSYGEFKCDNRVKQKLDRIPSFYNKNQLLS
KFKETKSYHPHHKKMGTVRCLNNNSEVPVTYPSISNMKLNKEKNRWEGNDIDLIRFEKPS
LITHKENKTKKRQGNMVYDEQNLRWINIESEHDVFDDIPDLAVKQLQSPVRGLSQFTQRT
TSTTATATAPSKNNETQHSDFEISRKLVDKFQKEQAKIEKKINHWFIDTTSEFNTDHYWE
IRKMIIEE
>A0A1D8PC38 A0A1D8PC38_CANAL Cta2p OS=Candida albicans (strain
MPENLQTRLHNSLDEILKSSGYIFEVIDQNRKQSNVITSPNNELIQKSITQSLNGEIQNF
HAILDQTVSKLNDAEWCLGVMVEKKKKHDELKVKEEAARKKREEEAKKKEEEAKKKAEEA
KKKEEEAKKAEEAKKAEEAKKVEEAAKKAEEAKKAEEEARKKAETAPQKFDNFDDFIGFD
INDNTNDEDMLSNMDYEDLKLDDKVPATTDNNLDMNNILENDESILDGLNMTLLDNGDHV
NEEFDVDSFLNQFGN
```

Edit:
The problem, as explained above, I face is that the output has additional '>' character for first sequence (only). I do not see the reason for the same and this is causing a lot of trouble. Output is:

```
Querying A0A1D8PC43
>A0A1D8PC43 A0A1D8PC43_CANAL Diphosphomevalonate decarboxylase
MYSASVTAPVNIATLKYWGKRDKSLNLPTNSSISVTLSQDDLRTLTTASASESFEKDQLW
LNGKLESLDTPRTQACLADLRKLRASIEQSPDTPKLSQMKLHIVSENNFPTAAGLASSAA
GFAALVSAIAKLYELPQDMSELSKIARKGSGSACRSLFGGFVAWEMGTLPDGQDSKAVEI
APLEHWPSLRAVILVVSDDKKDTPSTTGMQSTVATSDLFAHRIAEVVPQRFEAMKKAILD
KDFPKFAELTMKDSNSFHAVCLDSYPPIFYLNDTSKKIIKMVETINQQEVVAAYTFDAGP
NAVIYYDEANQDKVLSLLYKHFGHVPGWKTHYTAETPVAGVSRIIQTSIGPGPQETSESL
TK
Querying A0A1D8PC38
A0A1D8PC38 A0A1D8PC38_CANAL Cta2p OS=Candida albicans (strain
MPENLQTRLHNSLDEILKSSGYIFEVIDQNRKQSNVITSPNNELIQKSITQSLNGEIQNF
HAILDQTVSKLNDAEWCLGVMVEKKKKHDELKVKEEAARKKREEEAKKKEEEAKKKAEEA
KKKEEEAKKAEEAKKAEEAKKVEEAAKKAEEAKKAEEEARKKAETAPQKFDNFDDFIGFD
INDNTNDEDMLSNMDYEDLKLDDKVPATTDNNLDMNNILENDESILDGLNMTLLDNGDHV
NEEFDVDSFLNQFGN
```

Comment: Which part of the code do you think is supposed to remove `>` from the first line?

Comment: Only first sequence has '>' while others don't. That inconsistency is the problem.

Comment: Why not use Bioperl and it's fasta reading modules?

Comment: I considered and decided against as I do not want to have dependencies. It is not worth the installation as FASTA sequence extraction is the only useful piece in BioPerl that I need.

Answer (score 1):

`$/` is the input record separator, setting `local $/="\n>";` effect is that input is split into record ending with `\n>`, after chomp, the ending is removed however `/>*(\S+)/` may not match because `>` is consumed from previous record.

from FASTA wikipedia a line beginning by `>` is a comment and may not always be an id. However in case it is always the case, following may fix.

```
my ($id,$seq) = $seq =~ /^>*(.*)\n(\S+)/;
```

Comment: Thanks @Nahuel. The code works for 1st line of sequence and neglects rest of the (multi-line) sequence.

Comment: this is because `(\S+)` doesnt match newlines you may change with `([\S\s]+)` or `((?s).+)`

Comment: Ok, I understood now what `\n>` is doing so fixed the code by appending `>` for all non-first sequences. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You set the record separator to `\n>`. This does not apply to the first sequence.

Fixed code sequence:

```
...
chomp $seq;

# for first sequence
$seq =~ s/^>//;

my ($id) = $seq =~ /^(\S+)/;
if ($id eq $lookup) {
...
```

Please note that your implementation is extremely inefficient, because it reads & parses the file contents for each query. How about splitting loading/parsing and querying into separate functions?

Alternative solution: give the full list of lookup values to the loader. It would then fill an answer array as it encounters the matches during reading the file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Stefan. As it is inside a function it is not appropriate here (ie, without repeating part of the code). I need to repeat the extraction for ~40k sequences -- I have just shown the minimal code for demonstrating the problem.